# Visual C++ vs Visual C# , which is the best to learn?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I've done my C++ classes and practices after which I started learning Visual C++ using book Ivor Horton's Visual C++. The problem is that I am unable to understand the language of this book and badly trying to understand the codes. I want to learn Visual C++ for Windows application development and making my future in that (also because I already know C++).

Some of my friends told me to switch to C# since it has many library function to create GUI etc and told me it's hard to code Windows applications in Visual C++.

Now in these holidays I am going to join classes, can you help me which language I should stick to, and which one will be easy?

From very beginning I want to learn Visual C++ and sometimes I think it's hard when I don't understand concept in reference books etc.

Any help will be very appreciated, thanks a lot for taking your precious time.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Visual C++ and Visual C# are not **languages** nor **GUI frameworks**; they are **Integrated Development Environments** - IDEs. This means they are text editors tailored to the task of development.

Visual C++ lets you code in C++, Visual C# lets you code in C#. Also, both let you create GUIs in a point-and-click manner.

Sounds like what you really want to do is create GUIs. In that case, without having further information, I recommend you go for C#. It is a much cleaner language than C++, it has fewer ways to shoot yourself in the foot, and it provides access to the immensely useful .NET framework.

#### C# features that C++ doesn't have:

- Fully automatic memory management
- <strike>Lambda functions</strike>¹
- <strike>Type inference</strike>¹
- Reflection
- Remoting
- Automatic serialization
- True entity types
- Properties
- Database integration via LINQ
- Convenient functional-style programming via LINQ
- No header files
- No undefined behavior
- Direct interoperability with [many languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_.NET_Languages)
- Compile once, run everywhere

¹ these features have been added to C++ in the C++11 standard.

#### C++ features that C# doesn't have

- Template metaprogramming
- Typedefs
- Zero-overhead principle
- Means to enforce const-correctness
- Mature compilers that produce extremely optimized code nowadays
- Much wider platform support

Comment: For the last paragraph, you're missing the most important feature of C++ (wrt. C#): *deterministic memory management*.

Comment: I'd like to see this answer updated. C++11 has lambda functions and type inference.

Comment: I have been using C# for while, what is automatic serialization in C#? C# programmers use libraries (.NET or not) to manage serialization. Cant the same done with C++ too? :o

Comment: @nawfal: In C# the serialization libraries use usually reflection to figure out what data is contained in a given object graph. That's what I mean by automatic. You don't need to explicitly tell the serializer what data members are contained in your objects, but with C++ you do (even with libraries), as it doesn't have reflection.

Comment: @StefanMonov I see that but I had two problems with that. 1) 'Automatic' implies a language feature, at least for me. C# doesn't have any construct to do serialization, rather it is the library around it. May be a better choice of words would help here, like "C# helps serialization", or "It's easier to serialize in C#".  2) In any case, it is covered in the reflection part. It is the reflection which helps it in C#'s case. So may be it is better to be a sub point. Can I edit?

Comment: Visual C++ was an IDE, not anymore. Also, a comparison should be made side-by-side, unlike it is made now.

Answer (score 7):

> can you help me which language i should stick to , and which one will be easy.

In general, if you're goal is to develop Windows Applications, you'll probably find many, many more simple examples to learn from in C# than in C++.  There is a huge community around C# for Windows GUI development.

That being said, many of the concepts you'll need are the same in any language you learn.  You can't really go wrong - at some point, you'll probably want to learn both langauges if you're going to program professionally (as well as others).

> i think it's hard when i don't understand concept in ref books etc.

You should get a beginning programming book, not reference books, and go through it step-by-step.  If your goal is just GUI development, I'd recommend a good, simple C# book, and just step through it form beginning to end, and do all of the examples.  Learning from a "reference" book won't work - it's reference material, and not meant to teach concepts.

Answer (score 4):

**C++ vs. C# - a Checklist from a C++ Programmers Point of View** 
http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/03/06/c-vs-c-a-checklist-from-a-c-programmers-point-of-view/

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 4):

**C#** is the premeir .net language for developing applications on the .net framework.

**Native C++** is more cross platform and low level. It's used for writing applications for windows, mac, linux, embedded systems, etc.

**C++.net** is C++ adapted to the .net platform, and is primarily used for writing performance critical parts of an application (the rest of which is written in C#, VB.net, or something else as they integrate virtually seamlessly).

**Visual C++** is microsoft's windows compiler for C++ that can be used to write native and C++.net applications.

Writing .net applications solely in C++ in much harder than writing them in C# as you have to deal with more low level issues. If you want to write .net applications, I recommend using C# and C++.net if you need it.

Comment: There is no "C++.net", you mean **C++/CLR**. Also, writing in C++/CLR is hard, but not because it's lower-level (it's not). It's hard because the language uses C++'s old-school syntax with all the gotchas, while C# is designed from the ground up to fit with the .NET framework and to learn from C++'s mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

with C++, you could be able to touch the 'low level' near 'assembly things' part of programming

c# is never meant to be created to beat c++, with c# you get the whole .net framework utilities, faster cleaner form generations, with the lack of 'low level' part

Answer (score 2):

C# is largely intended for Business Applications so as Java. [Visual C# is Microsoft's implementation of the C# programming language specification, included in the Microsoft Visual Studio suite of products.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C_Sharp)

C# is much slower than C++, since the code passes through CLR. VC++.net has the same drawback.

VC++ is very hard to learn, so as MFC and windows programming, even though you know C++. But is it a prestigious and efficient language.

It is easy to switch from VC++ to VC#. But the reverse is harder.

If you go for VC++, MFC and Windows programming, try [this](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/).

Comment: "C# is much slower than C++".. naah.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider what you are likely to want to do in the future, as a professional or a hobbyist. Programming is a wide field, in which both languages have their place. If its too early for you to make that decision, C# is probably most likely to do you good in the future.

It's worth remembering that they are both only languages - and just as writing a good book is about more than correct spelling & grammar, writing good code is about more than the details of a particular languages syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would learn both.

Having said that, I would create GUI/Application projects using C#, and use VC++ for any COM or device communication.

I would check out [Which platform should I use : native C++ or C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273451/which-platform-should-i-use-native-c-or-c)