# could tell me if I can use the latest OpenGL in C#?

Tags: c#, opengl

you may be already tired of this question.

but please give me your time.

I mean, I am gonna use OpenGL, but I have no idea about that.

could you tell me that there is no problem if I use OpenGL in C#?

when I searched about OpenGl I got TaoFramework.

I think, this is not gonna update anymore, cuz Taoframwork.com is on sale at the moment.

1. Could I use the latest OpenGL in C#?
2. If C# is compared to C++ for OpenGL, is C++ better than C#?

Thanks for reading this and answering :)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981547/visual-c-versus-visual-c-sharp-which-is-the-best-to-learn and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536065/using-opengl-with-c :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) over Tao because it's far newer and adopts a system of generating the bindings from the OpenGL spec files. It also handles all of the context/window creation through `GameWindow` and `GLControl`, but still provides the ability to do your own context and window creation.

It also provides math classes (with the OpenGL bindings having method overloads for them), OpenAL bindings, and OpenCL bindings. It also works automatically cross-platform with Mono on Linux and OSX as long as you include the `.dll.config` files with the dll files.